# ASP.NET MVC4 coding error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

```
     @{
        var auction = new MvcAuction.Models.auction()
        {
        Title = "Example Auction",
        Description = " This is an example Auction ",
        Starttime = DateTime.Now,
        EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
        StartPrice = 1.00m,

        CurrentPrice=null;`

    };
    }
 <div class ="Auction" />
 <h3>@auction.Title</h3>
<div class="Details"></div>
<p> StartTime : @auction.Starttime.ToString("g")</p>
<p> EndTime:@auction.EndTime.ToString("g")</p>
<p>StartingPrice : @auction.StartPrice.ToString("c")</p>
<p> CurrentPrice:
    @if (auction.CurrentPrice == null)
    {
        @: [No Bids] 
    }
    else
    {
    <span>@auction.CurrentPrice.value.tostring("c")</span>
    }

</p>
```

> ***when i am running this code in visual studio 2012 it gives me an error***
>   error CS0037: Cannot convert null to 'decimal' because it is a non-nullable value type

```
>error CS1061: 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'decimal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: i am learnin asp.net mvc 4 and this code is an example in a video and it is supposed to run as the video shows but it gives me the same error every time

Answer (score 2):

C# is a case-sensitive language. You need Capital V in `Value`. And `ToString` needs to be camel case. This will allow the code to compile.

```
@auction.CurrentPrice.Value.ToString("c")
```